# change directive when scope variable changes

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using http request to get data from json file which I than use in controller.

```
    app.controller('mainCtrl', ['$scope', 'loaderService', function ($scope, loaderService) {
   //gets data from service 
        loaderService.getLoadedHtml().then(function (result) {
            $scope.fields = result.data;
        });
    }]);
```

I need to update directive when this `$scope.fields` change as

```
app.directive('dform', function () {
    return {
        scope: {
            action: '@',
            method: '@',
            html: '='
        },
        link: function (scope, elm, attrs) {
            var config = {
                "html": scope.fields
            };

            scope.$watch('fields', function (val) {
                elm.dform(config);
            });

            //console.log(config);
            //elm.dform(config);
        }
    };
})
```

and here is how I am using this directive

```
<div html="fields" dform></div>
```

But in my case when $scope.fields changes, i get `scope` as undefined in my directive $watch function.

**Question:**

How can I get the updated value for scope.fields in scope.$watch function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to give the directive access to `fields` by adding a binding for it:

```
scope: {
  action: '@',
  method: '@',
  html: '=',
  fields: '='
}
```

And HTML:

```
<dform fields="fields" ...
```

The value might be `undefined` the first time, then you don't want to call `dform`:

```
scope.$watch('fields', function(newValue, oldValue) {

  if (newValue === oldValue) return;

  var config = {
    "html": newValue
  };

  elm.dform(config);
});
```

---

### Update

With this HTML:

```
<div html="fields" dform></div>
```

You just need to watch `html` instead, no need for `$parent` or adding `fields` as a binding:

```
scope.$watch('html', ...
```

Comment: i don't want to create field as a new attribute here. I updated my question for better understanding.

Answer (score 1):

Usually for directives that should be as transparent as possible, no new scope is supposed be used. Having a new scope also prevents other directives from requesting a new scope on the same element.

If only one of the attributes is supposed to be dynamic, it is as simple as

```
scope: false,
link: function (scope, elm, attrs) {
    scope.$watch(function () { return scope[attrs.html] }, function (val) {
        if (val === undefined) return;

        var config = {
            action: attrs.action,
            method: attrs.method,
            html: val
        };

        elm.dform(config);
    });

}
```

Alternatively, `bindToController` can be used in more modern, future-proof fashion (depending on what happens with `html`, `$scope.$watch` can be further upgraded to `self.$onChanges` hook).

```
scope: true,
bindToController: {
    action: '@',
    method: '@',
    html: '='
},
controller: function ($scope, $element) {
    var self = this;

    $scope.$watch(function () { return self.html }, function (val) {
        if (val === undefined) return;

        var config = {
            action: attrs.action,
            method: attrs.method,
            html: val
        };

        $element.dform(config);
    });
}
```

Considering that `html="fields"`, the code above will watch for `fields` scope property.

Answer (score 0):

use `$parent.fields` instead of `fields`

Comment: @Umar Using $parent in a directive with isolated scope is antipattern.

Comment: @estus Thank you for the suggestion. Yes its against pattern, but I am in situation where I cannot use any workaround than this.

Comment: @Umar See the other answer, that's the correct one. It isn't obvious from your question why it isn't applicable here.

Comment: @estus Actually it is a jquery plugin. Here is it's full demonstration. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41323138/jquery-function-converted-to-directive-not-working-in-angular/
I just need fields. so html is extra here for me.

Comment: @Umar In this case I would suggest to use `bindToController` instead of isolated scope (like it is shown here http://stackoverflow.com/a/31415287/3731501). It allows to maintain proper scope hierarchy while still having bindings.

Comment: @estus I am not very good at angular, can you please post code for my case?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131514/discussion-between-umar-and-estus).